# How can I fix this duplicated classes error?

Tags: android, class, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library, but when I start build I have this error in build output:

```
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.3.1-runtime 
(androidx.core:core:1.3.1) and support-compat-26.0.2-runtime (com.android.support:support- 
 compat:26.0.2)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.3.1- 
runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) and support-compat-26.0.2-runtime (com.android.support:support- 
compat:26.0.2)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core- 
1.3.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) and support-compat-26.0.2-runtime 
(com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.2)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.3.1-runtime 
(androidx.core:core:1.3.1) and support-compat-26.0.2-runtime (com.android.support:support- ...

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

implementation 'com.github.FivesoftCode:SmartUtil:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.github.FivesoftCode:SimplePermissionRequest:1.0.2'

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')

implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0'


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
```

I was trying with *resolutionStrategy*, but with no success.
**Any ideas how to fix that?** 
I'll be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That library seems to be quite old. Did you try to find another one?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find a newer one which suits my needs. I've tried with BottomSheetBehavior from material design but I can't make the always visible menu in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

to **gradle.properties** worked for me.